# How to receive text from html page and validate it in the Controller side to only allow numbers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a small webpage having a text box and i want it take only number as input. How can I do that on the C# side. Please help me! I was thinking i need an if statement saying `if(userId = xxx !numbers)` then leave a message displaying please enter a number. I could  not figure it out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AlexUsers.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string userId = Request["UserId"];

            return View();
        }

    }
}




<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
    <div align="center">
        <form id="searchUser" method="post" action="">
            <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                Enter ID:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="searchButton" id="searchButtong">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
   </div>
   <hr /> 
</html>
```

Comment: c# runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the client. You cannot do this using c#.

Comment: bind the input to a 'number' property on a model and use the frameworks built in validation mechanism to do the check for you.  Asp.net mvc is cool like that:)

Answer (score 0):

After submit, you can use Integer.TryParse to check if input was integer.

```
string userId = Request["UserId"];
int userIdINT;
if(Int32.TryParse(userId,userIdINT)){       
    // your code here - userIdINT is an integer converted from userId (string) now

}
```